# How to delete multiple rows based on a query result

Tags: mysql

I have a query `SELECT id FROM log WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table)`. This query works fine however I want to delete all the rows that belong to this query result. How can I execute that delete using mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
DELETE FROM log WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table);
```